# Why is \markboth not working?

Tags: header-footer

I'm attempting to make my own headers for a book I'm writing. I want to alternate between two headings: "Left" and "Right"  My problem is: I'm not getting the Left and Right printing out when I use `\markboth`.

The code is

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics,color}
\usepackage[superscript]{cite}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markboth{Right}{Left}

First page
\newpage
Second page
\newpage
Third page
\newpage
Fourth page

 \end{document}
```

This provides:
[image]

2nd page:
[image]

But I want like this (below):
[image]

2nd page:
[image]

3rd:
[image]

4th:
[image]

Comment: Your example gives for me the correct result. Are you sure that you really tested this example and not another document which uses the documentclass option oneside?

Comment: Please refrain from posting "thank you"... Such forms of politeness are implied on TeX.SE.

Comment: Not following. You have swopped the order of terms in `\markboth` but your MWE is giving the output you desire (sort of)

Comment: Again I have tested it, but this gives the same result shown above which is not my required result. I am using "kile 2.1 beta 4" on ubuntu.

Comment: The first page also uses your heading style but I believe that when you insert a chapter the plain style will be used there. See here http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/3882/shutterseleo003.png

Answer (score 6):

The pictures you post of the desired output include a rule under the header and reducted margins.  For setting the margins the best choice is to use the `geometry` package.  For the headers the `fancyhdr` package provides the required facilities.  Using your syntax (which really has `Right` and `Left` the wrong way round), you can write:

[image: Sample page 2]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[vmargin=0.2cm,hmargin=1cm,head=16pt,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape\leftmark}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\markboth{Right}{Left}
\thispagestyle{empty}

First page
\newpage
Second page
\newpage
Third page
\newpage
Fourth page

\end{document}
```

`\pagestyle{empty}` ensures the first page (or the page that command is on) has no headers.

To use `\markboth` the standard way around you should use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[vmargin=0.2cm,hmargin=1cm,head=16pt,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape\rightmark}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\markboth{Left}{Right}
\thispagestyle{empty}

First page
\newpage
Second page
\newpage
Third page
\newpage
Fourth page

\end{document}
```