# \markboth is not working when using \chapter and \section

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr

I am having a problem when adding `\chapter` and `\section`  in the document. `\markboth` is not working when I compile it. I have got a link [Why is \markboth not working?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108722/why-is-markboth-not-working). But there is no solution about my problem. I have written the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[vmargin=0.2cm,hmargin=1cm,head=16pt,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape\leftmark}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\markboth{Chapter}{Section}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\chapter{ Chapter}
\section{Section}

\begin{theorem}
 Theorem
\end{theorem}

\newpage
Second page
\newpage

Third page
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]
[image]
[image]

But I want to get the following output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: If it is not possible in this way , tell me alternative way.

Comment: Not working isn't correct. You want a modification. This can be achieved by `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}` for section and `\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}`. For more details see the documentation with the examples of `fancyhdr`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

You have to redefine `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark` (after doing `\pagestyle{fancy}`). I have also reorganized a bit the code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[vmargin=0.2cm,hmargin=1cm,head=16pt,includeheadfoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,amsthm}

\pagestyle{fancy}
% We don't want chapter and section numbers    
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape\leftmark}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}

\begin{theorem}
 Theorem
\end{theorem}

\newpage
Second page
\newpage

Third page
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is working well.