# How to show only chapter number and chapter title as well as book title in header using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am writing a book in which I want to customize the headers and footers for the main matter. I want it to have the following style:

- nothing to be printed in the footer - (`\fancyfoot{}`)
- page number on the **E**ven-**R**ight and **O**dd-**L**eft pages - `\fancyhead[ER,OL]{\thepage}`
- book title on the even pages, close to the page number
- chapter number and chapter title on the odd pages, close to the page number (called with `\thechapter`)

I want to create a new style with:

```
\fancypagestyle{mainmatterstyle}{%
   \fancyfoot{}
   \fancyhead[ER,OL]{\thepage}
   the additional commands go here
}
```

Can anyone address me on how to do that?

I started reading the `fancyhdr` manual today and got stuck in section 15. I didn't understand the `\rightmark`, `\leftmark`, `\markboth` and `\markright` scoop.

My document has the following structure:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{mainmatterstyle}{
   % ⟨as above⟩
}
\title{My Book Title}
\author{Tush}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{mainmatterstyle}
\chapter{The first chapter}
   % ...Text goes here...
\end{document}
```

Is there a command, something like `\thebooktitle`, that prints the argument of `\title{}`?

Comment: Very similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111890/47927

Comment: Note that you cannot use `\chapter` to *get* the chapter name, since it is the command to actually *set* a new chapter name.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Right. I am going to delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\title{My Book Title}
\author{Tush}

\makeatletter
\let\thetitle\@title
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. #1}{\thetitle}}

\fancypagestyle{mainmatterstyle}{%
   \fancyfoot{}
   \fancyhead{}
   \fancyhead[ER]{\rightmark\makebox[3em][r]{\thepage}}
   \fancyhead[OL]{\makebox[3em][l]{\thepage}\leftmark}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{mainmatterstyle}
\chapter{The first chapter}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Let me quickly explain this: The title is internally stored in the macro `\@title`. To make it more easily accessible, I defined a new non-@ macro `\thetitle` to have the same contents using `\let`.

I then redefine the `\chaptermark` macro that is called every time a new `\chapter` starts and whose first argument (`#1`) is the chapter title. I tell this macro to call `\markboth` which takes two arguments: the mark for the left page and the mark for the right page, that can later be called using `\leftmark`  and `\rightmark`. Here, I use the `\thetitle` macro that I defined before.

The two macros `\leftmark`  and `\rightmark` then can eventually be placed inside the `\fancyhead` macro(s) to get the headers you want.

Comment: Thanks so much for your super quick reply. But, I am actually writing my document in Hebrew. And taking your solution to my MWE Hebrew tex file, I get rather a different result (the sections and their numbers are printed out). Should I start a new question about that or edit the original question?

Comment: I see. Well, better ask a new question, since this may involve some stuff that could render this answer not so useful anymore.

Comment: I prefer to define `\thetitle` rather than `\let` it as the real book title might well be too long for the headers.

Comment: Good point. Then, however, you could also hard-code the title in the relevant `\fancyhead` macro, actually.