# fancyhdr commands give different result when writing a document in Hebrew

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, hebrew

This question is a follow up to [my previous one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/625354/180429).

I am writing a book in Hebrew. I want the `mainmatter` of the book to have the following style in the headers and footers.

- nothing to be printed in the footer - (`\fancyfoot{}`)
- page number on the **E**ven-**R**ight and **O**dd-**L**eft pages - `\fancyhead[ER,OL]{\thepage}`
- book title on the even pages, close to the page number
- chapter number, the word chapter (translated to Hebrew) and chapter title on the odd pages, close to the page number (called with `\thechapter`)

My document at the moment reads the following

```
\documentclass{book}

%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername \ \thechapter \ #1}{כותרת הספר}}

\fancypagestyle{mainmatterstyle}{%
   \fancyfoot{}
   \fancyhead{}
   \fancyhead[ER]{\makebox[3em][r]{\textbf{\thepage}}\rightmark}
   \fancyhead[OL]{\leftmark\makebox[3em][l]{\textbf{\thepage}}}
}
%%
\usepackage{blindtext}
%%
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\title{כותרת הספר}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{mainmatterstyle}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: screenshot]

On page 2 here you can see that the header has the section in it (unwanted, I want the book title to be printed there) and on page 3 here you can see that the chapter number and title are printed (good).

I checked the answer by [Jasper Habicht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/47927) and it worked just fine in an English document.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sections still (by default) set `\sectionmark`, which puts the section title in `\rightmark`. You can eliminate this setting by switching off this `sectionmark` with

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
```

[image]